# Null pointer exception on Object class method

Tags: android

I am getting a null pointer exception and my app crashes.
I am getting a null pointer exception in my object class method getDistance()
and i am not able to figure out why i am getting the error

In this code I am getting the exception

```
private void readData() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "child added!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"value 
//changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            double distance = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : 
dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                SensorModel sensorModel = 
dataSnapshot.getValue(SensorModel.class);
                distance = 
Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(sensorModel).getDistance());

                if (distance < 10 )
                {
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    Notification notification = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setContentTitle(AppConstant.ALERT)

.setContentText(AppConstant.INTRUDER_DETECTED)

.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                            + getPackageName() + "/" + 
R.raw.intruder_alert))

                            .build();
                    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
                }

        }
```

My SensorModel.java

```
public class SensorModel {
private long date;
private long time;
private long humidity;
private String motion;
private String distance;
private String temperature;



public SensorModel(){

}
public SensorModel(long date, String distance, long humidity, String 
motion, String temperature, long time){
    this.distance=distance;
    this.date =date;
    this.motion = motion;
    this.temperature = temperature;
    this.humidity = humidity;
    this.time = time;
}

public long getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(long date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public long getHumidity() {
    return humidity;
}

public void setHumidity(long humidity) {
    this.humidity = humidity;
}

public String getMotion() {
    return motion;
}

public void setMotion(String motion) {
    this.motion = motion;
}

public String getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(String distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public String getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
}

public void setTemperature(String temperature) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
}
}
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
    at excel.com.sensordetector.service.IntruderDetectionService$1.
onChildChanged(IntruderDetectionService.java:63)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzbt.zza(Unknown 
Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.
zzdr(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown 
Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5615)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.
run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Please tell me why i am getting this exception in the readData method

Comment: Please provide the stack trace, so we can help you out properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because your distance string is empty, so you won't be able to parse it as Double.

Why don't you simply check for it?

Use:

```
if (distance != null && distance != 0) { }
```

If you want to check it after parsing.

But use:

```
if (distance != null && !distance.isEmpty()) { }
```

If you want to check the string before parsing.

Let me know if it helped.

---

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
public String getDistance() {

    if (distance == null || distance.isEmpty()) {
        return "0"; // we return 0 by default if we have nothing else to return
    }
    return distance; // else, we simply return the distance
}
```

Comment: Bro i am using it in a service so it is not applicable

Comment: What do you mean? It's always appropriate to check for nulls. You have to prepare your code for, sometimes, not receiving expected values. Especially if you are depending on external sources. From your LogCat, I can see your Double parser has no String to work with. Hence the NullPointer.

Comment: I updated the solution previously. See the UPDATE section on my answer :p

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear it. Please mark my answer as correct then. I'm trying to collect rep :D

Answer (score 0):

requireNonNull does not guarantee that you will get a non-null element. It just throws an error when the returned element is null. You are getting a null element, therefore your code is throwing an exception.